# IE8 refuses to load .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

**In Brief:**

My company is currently working on a small asp.net website to be used by a set of our customers. The site fails to load in only IE8 in our production environment, instead displaying a general page-not-found error (*not* a 404 from our server).

**Details:**

The website is deployed on two servers, QA and Prod. Both servers were cloned from the same image and should have identical settings. They have identical hardware and software. Both servers are outside of our company firewalls, accessible from the internet, as well as our company intranet. The website itself was deployed on both servers from the same build; the only difference is a single line in each site's web.config file pointing the site on Prod to the production database and the site on QA to a test database (whose data is cloned from Prod on a regular basis). I'll refer to our site on the QA server as *site.qa.com* and our site on the Prod server as *site.prod.com*.

When *site.prod.com* is accessed from the company intranet in any browser the site loads and behaves correctly (this includes accessing it in IE8). When *site.prod.com* is accessed from the internet (as our end users will be accessing it), *site.prod.com* loads and behaves correctly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE9. When we attempt to access it in IE8, IE8 returns a page-not-found error, as if the computer accessing *site.prod.com* is disconnected from the internet.

*site.qa.com* is accessible on both our intranet and the internet in every browser (including IE8).

I should also note that accessing *site.prod.com* from both the internet and our intranet uses the same URL and should pass through the same security checks; there's not a special intranet-only way of accessing either *site.prod.com* or *site.qa.com*.

**More about the servers:**

Both QA and Prod are running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Service Pack 1. We are running the website through IIS 7.5, and IIS settings are identical between the two servers (exporting their config files and comparing shows them matching down to the line).

**Closing:**

At this point we are stumped about why our website fails to load in IE8. It's not an option for us to drop support for IE8, and cloning QA and using that clone as Prod is a temporary solution we're considering, but won't answer our core question, which is: why will IE8 completely fail to load the production site, and only the production site, only when accessed from the internet?

**EDIT:**
The website magically started working (it looks to be one of *those* errors). I'll post here anything we're able to uncover about this behavior and how it was fixed, in case others are experiencing similar problems.

Comment: How many IE8's have you tried? same machine or multiple machines?

Comment: Also if you load up your test machine with IE8, what traffic does Fiddler see? What traffic does the server see?

Comment: We've tried IE8 on a multitude of machines from different internet access points (the coffee shop down the street from the office, at the end user's location a few states over, coworker's houses, etc.).

Fiddler sees normal traffic when accessing from the Intranet (it matches Chrome/FF traffic). I'll have to dig up Fiddler records for internet access.